# Why does HTML 5 not have editable combobox or local menus built in?

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering, in the new HTML 5, we will get <audio> and <video> tags, but why not native editable combobox and built in local menu support?

The reason I'm asking this is because these are the most common problems I face when I have to design a web solution to a typical table based application (e.g. order management app). On a proper client side app, I can use the OS to provide these facilities out of box (e.g. JPopupMenu, JComboBox). For a webapp, I have to look for javascript (libraries) to accomplish something like it.

*Why are these not in HTML 5?*

I know I should avoid discussion like questions, so here are some further questions: *Do you know libraries that can do the popup menu thing and editable combobox thing cheaply (perhaps with a small code sample)?*

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Actually, an editable combobox or just combobox can be created using the new list attribute on the input element. It points to a datalist element that can provide a list of predefined options:

```html
<input list=languages>
<datalist id=languages>
 <option value="English"></option>
 <option value="Dutch"></option>
</datalist>
```

For menus the old menu element has been reused.

You can use at least datalist in IE >=10, Firefox >=37, Chrome >= 39, Opera >= 29. Data from [caniuse datalist](http://caniuse.com/#search=datalist). About menu element, only Firefox seems to have a partial support for it.

Comment: Disclaimer: I work for Opera on HTML5 (among other things).

Comment: Nice job. Is there a way I could test it? I read the associated HTML5 spec, but I'm not sure it 100% covers my understanding of an editable combobox similar to its native counterpart.

Comment: Loading the above into a recent Opera build should do the trick. (9.x something would recent.)

Comment: See jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qdujy/). You can include a webshim for cross-browser support with browsers like IE9 [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qdujy/4/).

Comment: This seems to be working on Chrome too (I'm running 31.0.1650.57)

Comment: datalist is a poor substitute as it works as an autocomplete mechanism.  So if you have something in the input field already, only matching items from the list will be shown in the popup.  So you can't see what your choices are unless you clear the field first.

Comment: That really depends on the implementation. They don't have to work like that.

Answer (score 3):

The state of form and input controls on in browsers is a big mess in general.

- There's no consistency to implementation. Some use OS native controls (Safari), some use bespoke controls (Opera), and some use a mix of both (IE)
- Because of the above, styling/branding a form is not reliable
- Again because of the above, we suffer(ed) with z-index issues.
- Even on browsers where you can apply style, it's inconsistent.  Ever add a CSS border to `input` only to see squares around your radio buttons?

In general, I tend to agree with you. We've been living with the same form controls [since HTML 3](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/new.html).  So us web developers are left to create more rich and advanced controls on our own. And while these can work, they rely heavily on DHTML and can have significant usability implications.

It would be nice to see advancement in this area.

Answer (score 1):

these are easily doable with JavaScript, `<audio>` and `<video>` (and `<canvas>`!) aren't.

Relying on JavaScript libraries are not a bad thing.  If the browser did all, every webpage would look the same.

Comment: As are audio, video and canvas doable with flash and friends.

Comment: the goal is not to rely on plugins, like 'flash and friends'

Comment: The only drawback of the two multimedia tags are that they require either freely accessible content (imagine direct downloadable youtube content, horrible!), or custom codec plugins. My goal would be to not rely on javascript that much either.

Comment: I can "easily" make my own clothes and grow my own food too. I'm sure you could implement your own textbox. Have you? Why or why not? That's the original question. Is it really the 21st century with us having to ask these kinds of questions and get these kinds of answers? Oh, and I could really use a combobox too.