# Bootstrap select that allows text edit

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and have some select/dropdown boxes. They don't allow me to edit the text and I would like to make this select list an editable field so it can act as a select from existing or type a new value and click a Save to save it. How would I be able to do this via bootstrap (since my entire site is made with bootstrap).

So all I have today is the select below, but it doesn't allow the user to type into the select box. I guess I'm looking for a mix textbox and select/dropdown.

```
<select id="selectGroups" class="form-control" size="1">
   @foreach(var g in Model)
   {
      <option value="@g">@g</option>
   }
</select>
```

Comment: check this answer solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/1278634/2016070

Comment: check this answer solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/1278634/2016070

Answer (score 9):

This looks like it solves my issue.

[Why does HTML 5 not have editable combobox or local menus built in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1278431/why-does-html-5-not-have-editable-combobox-or-local-menus-built-in)

I just make the class of said input control to "form-control" and I get the bootstrap look.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on Select2 widget: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

It allows text editing, and also you can check out bootstrap theme for it: https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/

Comment: When I'm typing a new entry they all seem to not allow that. This seems to be mostly for searching what's in the list already.

Answer (score 0):

Using input type text and data list:

```
<input type="text" id="selectGroups" class="form-control" list="mylist">
<datalist id="mylist">
    <option value="One">
    <option value="Two">
    <option value="Three">
    <option value="Four">
    <option value="Five">
</datalist>
```

it is text box but like with searching suggestion or auto complete, but user can double click the text box to being appear like select option.

Or, you can using more library like : http://indrimuska.github.io/jquery-editable-select/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264640/how-can-i-create-an-editable-dropdownlist-in-html).

There are two approaches. One uses the HTML5 `<datalist>` tag.
The other one uses an input field in front of the dropdown. If the user selects a dropdown item, the value will be filled with JavaScript into the input field.

Answer (score -2):

Old, but I found this while running into the same problem.
My solution - Use a Dropdown and replace the button with a text input

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control dropdown-toggle" id="myInputId" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" />
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="myInputId">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```